# How to hide a gui canvas after some time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am displaying a canvas in Unity 3D that shows the instructions of the game at the beginning of the level, which I want to be hidden after 5-6 seconds. ( I don't want to do it with keyDown)

I was wondering what is the best way/practise to do it?

Is it using Animation? Or using some asynchronous methods like coroutine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerator hideUI (GameObject guiParentCanvas, float secondsToWait,bool show = false)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (secondsToWait);
    guiParentCanvas.SetActive (show);
}
```

To call it, simply start the coroutine and pass in the name of the parent gameobject that contains the UI then pass in how many seconds you want it to wait for before hiding UI canvas. The third parameter is optional and is there if you want to show that UI again. Pass true to it to display that hidden GUI again.

Usage:

```
    StartCoroutine (hideGUI (gameObject, 2.0f)); //Wait 2 seconds then hide UI
    StartCoroutine (hideGUI (gameObject, 2.0f, true)); //Wait 2 seconds then show UI
```

Answer (score 1):

With Unity, they have a WaitForSeconds function that will wait for x seconds, then do something. You can use this so when the level starts up, you wait 5-6 seconds then hide the GUI.

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds (5);
// GUI hide code
```

Answer (score 1):

May use a delayed [`Invoke`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html), like:

```
public class Hide : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float after = 5.0f;

    void Start()
    { Invoke("Disable", after); }

    void Disable()
    { gameObject.SetActive (false); }
}
```

Or you can use `Start()` returning `IENumerator`, like:

```
public class Hide : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float after = 5.0f;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(after);
        gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```